# On the continuity of non constant functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f$ is a non constant continuous function. Doesn't $f(x+\epsilon) \neq f(x)$ for some $\epsilon \to 0$ imply that we need to "lift our pen to draw the next point" and thus $f$ can't be continuous?
I mean it in the sens that, were we to be able to have a just next point to $x$, there will be a "jump". This is of course necessary for a function to be non constant, but suppose $f(x)=x^\alpha$ with $\alpha \to \infty$, that jump would be considerable.

Comment: Obviously this is not how continuity is actually defined; it's just a saying to give people an intuition for what the graphs of real-valued continuous functions look like. I guess, one way of saying it is " if $f$ is continuous at $x$, to draw the point $f(x+ \varepsilon)$, you lift your pen less and less as $\varepsilon \to 0$". If this isn't satisfactory, you would have to make your question more precise/ dig deeper and ask youself what is it about continuity that is bothering you. Then perhaps someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: I have no problem tracing the curves $y=x,y=x^2,\dots$ near $0.$

Comment: @peek-a-boo I mean it in the sens that, were we to be able to have a just next point to $x$, there will be a "jump". This is of course necessary for a function to be non constant, but suppose $f(x)=x^\alpha$ with $\alpha \to \infty$, that jump would be considerable.

Comment: @Luyw And to make the "jump" smaller, you would have to make $\varepsilon$ smaller and smaller. but if it's really bothering you so much, I'd suggest you take a look at the $\varepsilon$- $\delta$ definition of continuity, because it formalizes the notion of "$f(x)$ approaches $f(a)$ as $x$ approaches $a$"

Comment: @Luyw Part of your difficulty may be thinking about the "just next point". There is no such thing, no positive number "right after $0$". The formal definition of continuity with epsilons and deltas was invented in order to make rigorous arguments without referring to a next point. That logic replaces the idea of "infinitely close" by the idea of "as close as you wish".

Comment: Thank you peek-a-boo and Ethan.

Comment: @EthanBolker about getting as close as I wish, putting aside the infinitesimally close, there needs to be a tangible change for the values to be non constant. I hovered over the continuity tag and it showed "Intuitively, a continuous function is one where small changes of input result in correspondingly small changes of output." and I guess this answers my question more in the sens that it is by looking at the change that we judge the continuity of a function.